# Xamarin.Forms PCL project fails to load custom component defined in another PCL project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project and it has a structure like this:

[image]

The main PCL project is the first one and it has a reference to the last one.

I created a component in the last PCL project and intended to use it in the main PCL project.

[image]

Unfortunately when the view is instantiated, I get the following exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.MyComponents' or one of its
>   dependencies"

What else should I set?

Comment: Faced with the similar problem. I had custom control in separate PCL project. Found out some workaround - in constructor of a `Page` before `InitializationComponent` put your control initialization like `var c = new SomeControlFromAnotherProject();`.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Thanks for the tip. It loads now, but I get another exception: `LoadTemplate should not be null`. According to this (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35603/exception-loadtemplate-should-not-be-null-xamarin-1-4-0-6341), I should create the template in the code. It seems that reusing components is not what Xamarin intended to support.

Comment: The error is telling you what the issue is - 'could not load file or one of its dependencies'. First of all, delete all bin and obj folders, do a clean and then rebuild. If the error remains you need to cross reference the dependencies on each PCL and make sure they are aligned. Consider the PCL profile level and their compatibility.

Comment: Is your XAML file referencing (with a xmlns directive) an assembly called Xamarin.MyComponents?  Does Xamarin.MyComponents.dll exist in the output directory, where the .exe file is generated?

Comment: @DavidS Yes, I have the necessary _xmlns_ in my XAML file and the dll is in the output folder.